# printf %s const char*

Tags: c++, c++11

`printf`'s `%` conversion specifier expects a pointer to a `char` array. Note the lack of `const`. I can see the reasons for this in C, and since C++ incorporates the C99 standard, this wouldn't change. However, if I'm writing my own `printf`, can I safely convert the argument to `const char*` instead?:

```
case 's' :
    ptr = va_arg(va, const char*);
    _puts(ptr, strlen(ptr));
    break;
```

Would this have any unintended semantics (note: I'm not asking about undefined behavior, because such an implementation would not be conforming anyway)?

Comment: why on earth do you need ellipsis printf in c++11????

Comment: Answering direct question, it is not going to have any effect. va_arg is a macro, and it will simply use whatever type you have provided.

Comment: You can call a function with `char const *` using a non-const variable.  So I recommend you using the `char const *` type in your function.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (E)) specifies the meaning of the `%s` conversion specifier in 7.21.6.1/8:

> If no l length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type.

This formulation clearly not specific enough to tell whether the character type is `const` or non-`const`. It doesn't even state whether `char`, `signed char`, or `unsigned char` is used. I don't think *character array* is defined as a term in the C standard.

Put differently: using `char const*` for the type specified by a `%s` conversion specifier is fine.

Comment: Also relevant is that the standard specifies that `char *` and `const char *` have the same size and representation etc., so the `va_arg` still succeeds